How Facebook conversions API works
I was reading the documentation for the Conversions API because we are considering using it to track our offline conversions. However, I have some doubts that I would like to clear up. Can anyone here help me with that?

In the document, it's mentioned that the "fbclid" is not required, so I want to know how Facebook will identify from which ad campaign this conversion occurred.
What will be the Event ID in the payload? for example, if I'm tracking events for 'Order completed' then event_id should be the same for all Order Completed events or it should be unique for the events with the same name but for different users.
How long can I push past events, as the document states up to 7 days for server-side events and 62 days for offline events? I would like to gain a deeper understanding of this.
What are the expected error codes from Conversions API I didn't find it in the documentation.

